# Error cargando hoja de exel.csv a la base de datos desde php y ajax

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, ajax, base-de-datos

Estos son los errores que presenta:

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\laragon\www\Sustentacion\Vista\Formulario\cargamasiva\import.php on line 6
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\laragon\www\Sustentacion\Vista\Formulario\cargamasiva\import.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined variable: contactList in C:\laragon\www\Sustentacion\Vista\Formulario\cargamasiva\import.php on line 18
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\laragon\www\Sustentacion\Vista\Formulario\cargamasiva\import.php on line 18
```

Aqui dejo los scripts:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function uploadContacts()
    {

        var Form = new FormData($('#filesForm')[0]);
        $.ajax({

            url: "import.php",
            type: "post",
            data : Form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert('Registros Agregados!');
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

```css
<?php

include('../../../Conexion/conexion.php');

$fileContacts = isset($_FILES['fileContacts']); 
$fileContacts = file_get_contents($fileContacts['tmp_name']); 

$fileContacts = explode("\n", $fileContacts);
$fileContacts = array_filter($fileContacts); 

// preparar contactos (convertirlos en array)
foreach ($fileContacts as $contact) 
{
    $contactList[] = explode(",", $contact);
}

// insertar contactos
foreach ($contactList as $contactData) 
{
    $conexion->query("INSERT INTO FUNCIONARIO 
                        (NUMERO_DE_DOCUMENTO,
                        NOMBRE_FUNCIONARIO,
                        APELLIDO_FUNCIONARIO,
                        CELULAR_FUNCIONARIO,
                        CONTRASENA_FUNCIONARIO,
                        ROL_FUNCIONARIO_FK)
                         VALUES

                         ('{$contactData[0]}',
                          '{$contactData[1]}', 
                          '{$contactData[2]}',
                          '{$contactData[3]}',
                          '{$contactData[4]}',
                          {$contactData[5]}
                           )

                         "); 
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">
    <head> 
        <title>CARAGA DE DATOS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h3>Carga Funcionario </h3>
            </div>
        </header>

        <form action="files.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="filesForm">
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="fileContacts" >
                <button type="button" onclick="uploadContacts()" class="btn btn-primary form-control" >Cargar</button>
            </div>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Todo el error viene de la linea 5 en la que tienes

```
$fileContacts = isset($_FILES['fileContacts']);
```

Al usar `isset` el valor de $fileContacts sería booleano, por tanto fallará el resto del código, me imagino que al revisar con isset compruebas su existencia, por tanto usa lo siguiente

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileContacts'])) {
    $fileContacts = $_FILES['fileContacts'];
    // El resto del código
}
```